# Adding undetermined white space above a bootstrap 3 affix/scrollspy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If you check out this link, you will see that as you scroll down, the navigation has both affix and scrollspy functionality (From bootstrap 3)

http://codepen.io/datanity/pen/thnua

However, if you add white space at the top, the affix/scrollspy occurs in the wrong location.  For example, this is with 800px of white space ontop.

http://codepen.io/datanity/pen/haKzg

Now of course here, you can adjust the affix/scrollspy code so that way it works with the 800px height ontop but, my problem is that I have no idea what space I will have on top.  Sometimes it will be 2000px other times only 300px.    Also, there is no way for me to know the id/class of the divs that appear ontop.  Sometimes it will be 10 divs, sometimes 0, and they will always have different id/classes.

Is there a way that the affix and scrollspy can be triggered relative to the container it is in, and not a fixed px location from the top of the body?

Thanks for any help!
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding this to the top of the js fixed the issue.  With this method, it does not matter how much white space or how many divs you have ontop.  Your bootstrap scrollspy and affix will always be in the correct place!

```
$('#mynav').affix({
  offset: {
    top: $('#mynav').offset().top
    , bottom: function () {
      return (this.bottom = $('.bs-footer').outerHeight(true))
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the section element (located at the top of the HTML page). I'm assuming this is the element that you're concerned about changing heights.

```
<section id="top-section" style="height:800px;">
</section>
```

Then add these lines to your JS file:

```
var $h = $("#top-section").height() + 280;
$("#mynav").attr("data-offset-top", $h);
```

This queries the rendered height of the section element, and then fixes your sidebar response height accordingly.

If you will also have an unknown amount of sections, then you should wrap the code that creates the sections in a div element. For instance, if you're using PHP to build the section area of your webpage, you should do something like this:

```
<div id="section-wrapper">
    <?php echo "Whatever code you have here" ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You can change the height of the section element to test it out.

Comment: Awesome suggestion!  For my purposes though, that unfortunately will not work.  Due to the nature of the site I am building, there is no way for me to tell how many sections will be on top, and what their id's or classes will be.  For example, there may be 10 seconds ontop with 10 different ids.  Or there may be 1 section ontop, or none.  

Is there a way to have the affix/scrollspy appear according to the location of the container that holds it?

Comment: You should wrap the code that dynamically creates the sections in a div. Then just query the id of that div. See my edit for an example.